# play video in tableview using url in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, url, video

hi trying to load a video in mytableview till now didn't work in the videos in table view I have no idea so some where I have to something I'm not getting the video. using the url I want to play the videos.

**this is my tableview .h file;**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "vediopoliticalCell.h"
@interface politicalViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;
@end
```

**this is my tablecell.h file code:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface vediopoliticalCell : UITableViewCell


@property (strong,nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController * movieplayer;

@end
```

**this is my tablecell.m file code:**

```
  @implementation vediopoliticalCell
  @synthesize movieplayer;

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
   {
     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {
     // Initialization code
    }
       return self;
   }

  - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 { 
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
  }
```

**and this is my tableview.m file code:**

```
    #import "politicalViewController.h"
    #import "vediopoliticalCell.h"

    @interface politicalViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation politicalViewController
    @synthesize mytableview;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
      [super viewDidLoad];


 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }


    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

         return 1;
     }
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
         return 10;
     }

   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

         vediopoliticalCell *cell = (vediopoliticalCell *)[tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         if (cell==nil) {

          cell= [[vediopoliticalCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

           }

           NSURL * url  = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost/image/vedios/iOS%20Tutorial-%20JSON%20Part%204%20-%20Loading%20data%20from%20an%20external%20database%20into%20an%20app.mp4"];


          cell.movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

         [cell.movieplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 50)];
         [self.view addSubview:cell.movieplayer.view];

            return cell;
       }
```

after doing this coding my just getting the empty tableview i'm not able to bring the video in the table cell can any tell me where i'm doing wrong what is the correct procedure to get the videos

Comment: Why are you adding table view cell in self.view?

Comment: You should add movie player view as subview of cell in cell's layoutSubView method.

Comment: in  tableView:didSelect method call [cell.movieplayer play];

Comment: thanks for ur answer @fibnochi can pls tell where im doing the mistake how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not use property for **play** or **prepareToPlay** `MPMoviePlayerController`.add

```
[cell.movieplayer play] or [cell.movieplayer prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: im not even able to bring that video  and i have tried with ur codes also its not working im just getting the a empty tableview thats all

Answer (score 0):

U can use this code, it might works fine

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

     vediopoliticalCell *cell = (vediopoliticalCell *)[tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     if (cell==nil) {

      cell= [[vediopoliticalCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

       }

       NSURL * url  = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost/image/vedios/iOS%20Tutorial-%20JSON%20Part%204%20-%20Loading%20data%20from%20an%20external%20database%20into%20an%20app.mp4"];


      cell.movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

     [cell.movieplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 50)];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.movieplayer.view];
     [cell.movieplayer.view setHidden:NO];
     [cell.movieplayer.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [cell.movieplayer prepareToPlay];
     [cell.movieplayer play];

        return cell;

   }
```

This will play the video on the custom cell not on the main view

and Before this plz also cross check whether "url" containing file path "http://localhost/image/vedios/iOS%20Tutorial-%20JSON%20Part%204%20-%20Loading%20data%20from%20an%20external%20database%20into%20an%20app.mp4" is returning right file/path or nor ?